# Is intergration and an integral the same thing?

Tags: calculus

And if not whats the difference? I think the integral is the area under the curve and integration is an anti derivative (what ever that means)

Comment: It's the same thing. Take $f$ a function and $A(t)$ the area under its curve from $x=0$ to $x=t$. Then $A(t+dt)=A(t)+f(t)\times dt$ because you add a little rectangle (or rather something that can be approximated by a ractangle for a small enough $dt$) of height $f(t)$ and width $dt$ to get from the are $A(t)$ to the area $A(t+dt)$. So indeed, $A'(t)=f(t)$. That's completely informal and isn't a proof but it should help you understand what's hapenning.

Comment: To evaluate the integral $\int f(x) dx$ you must integrate $f(x)$.

Comment: What do you mean by A(t), dt and A'(t)?

Answer (score 4):

The words "An integral" represent a noun -- defined as the area under a curve (or, when you get more advanced, some other sort of limit of sums).

The word "integrate" is a verb; the act of computing an integral.

The word "integration" is a noun refering to the general concept of doing the (verb) integrrate.  As in

"Integration is not hard, you just take the anti-derivative of a function and you obtain the integral of that function"

or

"Not hard?  I can't even integrate $e^{x^4}$ because I can't find the anti-derivative"

Answer (score 2):

One is the object: the integral, the other is the act of "finding" the integral.

" the mathematician wanted to find the integral of $f$, so the mathematician used integration"

Answer (score 0):

Integration is the process of computing the integral of a function. The function being integrated is known as the integrand.

The integral is also known (less commonly) as the anti-derivative, because integration is the inverse of differentiation (loosely speaking).

Integrals are indefinite when there are no bounds imposed, and the result is a family of functions (dependent on the variable of integration) and separated only by an arbitrary additive constant. When an upper and lower bound are specified (as numbers), it is called a definite integral, and the final answer (the integral) is no longer a function dependent on the variable of integration, but just a single number. This is the sort of integral used to calculate the area under a curve between two bounds.

Technically, there are different "flavours" of integral. The most common type is the Riemann Integral, which is the limit of a Riemann Sum. But there are other sorts like the Lebesgue Integral, which is defined differently and not commonly used in elementary courses.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes "integral" is used to refer to *integers*.  In that case you would not use "integration" when talking about it.